# Can I save a DMBL layout as a jpeg/png?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, layout, linq-to-sql, printing, diagram

Is it possible to save the layout diagram from a DBML file as a jpeg/png or any other image format?

A manager wants to know what we are storing in our database and the print out wasn't enough he wants an electronic version.

I know I can use a screen-shot but wonder if there are any other options? I've just thought about printing to a PDF printer as well. Still would be nice if there was a save to PNG

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I just used a PDF printer which worked quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a MSOffice user, you can use Microsoft OneNote (copy diagram over there and then export it to a PNG), or you can use [Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots), which is basically a nice tool for taking *screen shots* out of portions of the screen.